# Is it possible to limit folder size in a Windows environment?

Tags: windows, directory

Is it possible to limit a folder size in Windows so that when a user tries to write to the folder when it is full he receives an error message?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that Disk Quotas are per user not per folder, there are other solutions that will allow you to lock down a folder size regardless of user, my experience has been with Veritas Storage Exec, but it seems to be discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean **disk quotas** as described at, e.g. http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-Disk-Quotas-Windows-2003.html?

Comment: Dagnabit, Rob, every question I answer, I answer about 20-30 seconds after you with the same info.  :(  ;)

Comment: Can you define quotas per folder?

Comment: I don't believe disk quotas will work. The followring text is from the link in your answer "Disk quotas are configured on a per volume basis and cannot be set on a file or folder level."

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Quotas](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ntfs+quota) for NTFS file systems..

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Server 2008 Administrator's Companion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163561.aspx) recommends using the [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754810%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) instead of the older "disk quota" feature since these allow per-directory settings. (I'm not familiar with this tool myself; after 5 mins of playing around with it, I still have no idea how to actually do this. There certainly is a column for "quota", however.)

Another trick is to create a new volume and then use a symbolic link (see [MKLINK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) to map the directory to that volume. (MKLINK is Vista/2008 and later; for XP/2003 use [NTFS junctions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx).)

Comment: The symlink trick is probably the best way to go about it for Win7

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how limiting you want to be. :)

For example, it's not difficult to write a program that listens/monitors a folder and displays a message box error/warning in case the user exceeds his quota. But that doesn't *prevent* him from exceeding it - just notifies him he did so.